# Bootstrap/Javascript: How to have a glyphicon/popover display next to the form inputs that don't validate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate a form using bootstrap and JavaScript, but am struggling to get my validateForm function to change the css value. But even if this does eventually work, I am stuck needing to reset my css after the submit button has been clicked again. Should I be going about this another way? This is what I have:

```
//section of form 

<form name="registration">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
       <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
       <span class = "icon hidden"><a href="#" title="Field Error" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="First Name cannot be blank and is not a name format">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true">
           </span>
       </a></span>
       <input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text"><span id="fnameError"></span>
   </div>

//more inputs similar format as above, then concluding with the submit button
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up" id="regisClick">Register and proceed to checkout</button>

//css
/*error icon*/
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign{
    color: red;
}
.hidden>.glyphicon-exclamation-sign{
    display: none;
}
/*popover*/
.popover-title{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.popover-content{
    font-weight: bold;
}

//js
var formInputs = [
  [document.forms["registration"]["fname"].value, /^[a-zA-Z]/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["lname"].value, /^[a-zA-Z]/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["address"].value, /^\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["city"].value, /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["zipcode"].value, /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["phone"].value, /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["email"].value, /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)@([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)[\\.]([a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["password"].value, /(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/],
  [document.forms["registration"]["confirmPassword"].value,   document.forms["registration"]["password"].value],
  ]

document.getElementById("regisClick").addEventListener("click", validateForm);

function validateForm(inputs){
  for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     if(inputs[i][0] = '' || !inputs[i][1].test(inputs[i][0])){
        document.getElementsByClassName("icon hidden")[i].style.display= 'unset';
        return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI `unset` isn't supported in IE. you'll probably want to use properties 'display` and `block`